# Load and parse XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have to create a webservice which goes to a specific URL that returns a **XML-file** as response and interprets/parses this file in order to save its contents to a MySQL database.

I've heard about the **SimpleXML** but I'm not sure how to get the websites response into a file whose path is needed in order to parse the document.

Can somebody at least explain me how to reach the goal of downloading the XML and saving it to a file? (best with some PHP code)
I will then (hopefully) find out by myself how to parse it and store its contents.

[Here](http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/simple.xml)'s an example of what my XML will look like (for privacy reasons I can't publish the real URL I'm using...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of pointers..

To download a file and save it, the easiest way I have found is this:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('saved.xml', file_get_contents('http://www.xmlfiles.com/examples/simple.xml'));
```

You can then open the file with the simpleXML library like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('saved.xml');
var_dump($xml);
```

Hope that gives you enough info to get started.

See [simpleXML](http://php.net/simpleXML) for info on the simpleXML library.

Comment: There is no need to save the file, you could just pass the URL as a parameter of simple_xml_load_file function. For example you can do this: $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml_file_url');

Answer (score 1):

You can download and save the xml to a local file by doing this:

```
$xmlstring = file_get_contents("http://domain.com/webservice/xmlfile.xml");
file_put_contents("path/localxmlfile.xml", $xmlstring);
```

To parse the xml file I suggest you to use `DOMDocument` class in combination with the `DOMXPath` class to query/search for specific elements.

DOMDocument: http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php

DOMXPath: http://php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can find your answer on below link. Seems related topic.

[How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml)